# Get images synchronously with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to overlay 1 image on top of another. For that I am using 2 Glide calls each to crop and resize both the images. I take bitmap as an output from these calls and overlay one on top of other. After this I need to upload this newly generated to the server.
But, issue right now is, before Glide returns, the upload process is already completed with the old image (which was already present in the object before Glide calls) without the overlay.

Can someone please help me on can I get this done synchronously so that I get he images first and then I can start the upload?

Below is one of the calls. Second is exactly the same pulling a another image from Drawable

```
FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureTarget =
                    Glide.with(ctx)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(imgUri)
                            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .override(width, height)
                            .centerCrop())
                            .submit(ogWidth, ogHeight);
            src = futureTarget.get();
```

Comment: Glide has a built in onComplete listener, that will help

Comment: Hi Yunus, thanks for that. I used onResourceReady event which worked just fine. But now, I am running into OOM when there are than 2 or 3 items to be processed. Any suggestions?